# Why these two summations are equivalent?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, analysis

I am reading a paper about [Kadison-Singer Problem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1809.03255) . There is a technical step that I cannot understand, which is labeled red  in the picture.

[image]

In the picture, $\Phi_k>0$ when $1\leq k\leq r$ and $\Phi_k=0$ when $k>r$, which means that all the summations mentioned above are finite summations. And I cannot figure out why those two inequalites are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well
$$\delta-1=\left(\frac{\delta^1}{1!}-\frac{\delta^{1-1}}{(1-1)!}\right)\frac{\Phi_1}{\Phi_1}$$
So the first expression reads
$$\sum_{k=1}^r\left(\frac{\delta^k}{k!}-\frac{\delta^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\right)\frac{\Phi_k}{\Phi_1}\ge0$$
Then we have
$$\frac{\delta^k}{k!}-\frac{\delta^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=\frac{\delta^{k-1}(\delta-1)}{k!}+\frac{\delta^{k-1}}{k!}-\frac{\delta^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=\frac{\delta^{k-1}}{k!}(\delta-1)-\frac{\delta^{k-1}}{k!}(k-1)$$
So
$$(\delta-1)\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{\delta^{k-1}}{k!}\frac{\Phi_k}{\Phi_1}\ge\sum_{k=1}^r(k-1)\frac{\delta^{k-1}}{k!}\frac{\Phi_k}{\Phi_1}$$
And since all the terms in the sum on the left hand side are positive we can divide to get
$$\delta-1\ge\frac{\sum_{k=1}^r(k-1)\frac{\delta^{k-1}}{k!}\frac{\Phi_k}{\Phi_1}}{\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{\delta^{k-1}}{k!}\frac{\Phi_k}{\Phi_1}}$$